# Problem playing online videos on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: video, flash

I have the latest, Ubuntu 16.04, with the latest Firefox and Adobe Flashplayer version 11. Videos from YouTube, Vimeo, etc. are working fine. But no video from [Star Sports](http://www.starsports.com/cricket/index.html) will play. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Adobe doesn't really support Linux anymore. Your best bet for playing online videos is using chrome, as Google has integrated flash player into the chrome browser.

Comment: Chrome is not available for 32bit. Where to get 32bit latest chrome for ubuntu?

Comment: Unfortunately, Google just doesn't support 32-bit Linux anymore, either :(. I found a 3rd-party version of Flash Player called Fresh Player which should work on Firefox. You can read more [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/install-fresh-player-plugin-in-ubuntu.html).

Comment: Can you please open the address `about:plugins` in Firefox and include a screenshot of the part(s) about Flash Player in your question?

Comment: Here is a screenshot after opening about:plugins in firefox                                              http://i.imgur.com/NaUgX7Y.png

Answer (score 7):

The old way of installing Adobe Flash with `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer` is no longer supported. Instead, you need to use **Fresh Player**.

### To Install

As of 16.04, Fresh Player is available in the official repositories. Installing is as simple as:

```
 sudo apt-get install browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash
```

However, if you still want the *most* up-to-date version, you can add the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash
```

This will install the actual player, but it still needs an extra file. This file is the actual `pepperflash` library used by the player. To get it, you can use a PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:skunk/pepper-flash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pepflashplugin-installer
```

Close your browser and re-open, and it should be enabled. The reason Youtube and Vimeo worked most likely was because of the support of HTML5 video on those websites.

Source: [WebUpd8 Team](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/install-fresh-player-plugin-in-ubuntu.html)

Comment: After installing Fresh Player Videos not playing It show me some error. http://i.imgur.com/K15gwZQ.png

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a step.

Comment: No its not working

Comment: Worked for me on 16.10

Comment: tried to do this for 14.04, returned error message upon install - no go?

Comment: This guide fails on Ubuntu 16.04, the file `libpepflashplayer.so` does not get installed.