# Videos not playing in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: video, vlc

I searched, and searched and searched some more for hours to no avail.

I tried using Firefox, Chrome and Chromium, and also tried downloading Flash, pepper flash, using html5 and a slew of other options. Looked here, at documentation, reddit and can't find a sensible answer that works.

Videos simply load, but don't play.

What's the work around? What do you have to do to be able to watch a video on youtube?

First day trying linux/Ubuntu and I'm a tad frustrated.

EDIT:

Adam:

first command

```
Package: flashplugin-installer
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: contrib/web
Installed-Size: 58
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: foreign
Source: flashplugin-nonfree
```

Second Command output

```
dpkg-query: package 'adobe-flashplugin' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
```

third comman g streamers:

It's very arcane and long. It does start with this message though:

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
```

Angel:

That worked! No audio though....

ANOTHER EDIT:

Now I can't even acess my OS. VM asks for password upon reboot, seems to login, then goes straight to login screen again (password is correct).

Comment: What have you tried? Please help us help you! Did you try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/768493/problem-playing-online-videos-on-ubuntu-16-04?rq=1

Comment: This is weird. Does this happen if you try to play a video with VLC? I.e. execute from terminal `vlc https://youtube.com/some-video-link`.

Comment: sudo apt-get install pepflashplugin-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pepflashplugin-installer

Comment: Have you tried the Adobe version of Flash? What is the output for  dpkg -s flashplugin-installer and dpkg -s adobe-flashplugin? I assume that you have tried: sudo apt update, sudo apt upgrade, sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras before installing Flash, did you?

Comment: @Ryan ah, sorry, unfortunately some youtube videos trigger 403 error for VLC, the one you tried doesn't work for me either. Try this one instead `vlc https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=csoGNK1bC_8`.

Comment: One more question, what gstreamer packages you have.  You can check that using this: apt list | grep gstreamer

Comment: Edited my answer for better formatting to answer questions

Comment: If you run a browser with video from a terminal, do you see any errors in the output?

Comment: You made a typo, you probably wanted to say not "VM asks for password", but "DM asks for password". What did you do before that?