# flash videos won't play in any browser

Tags: 16.04, firefox, google-chrome, 64-bit, flash

I used to play streams from [crictime](http://live.crictime.com/) and they used to play without any problem in both firefox and chrome, but they won't anymore. Youtube videos play without any problem. I have already seen [Problem playing online videos on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768493/problem-playing-online-videos-on-ubuntu-16-04)  on *askubuntu*. The suggestions posted as solutions haven't worked for me.

Some information regarding software version:

```
 Google Chrome: 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit)  
 Firefox:  53.0.3 (64-bit)  
 browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash is already the newest version (0.3.6-1~webupd8~xenial6)
```

I have also enabled flash for all sites in chrome. I would really appreciate the community to help me identify and solve the problem.

Comment: Try removing that `browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash` package and installing `adobe-flashplugin` instead. You have to restart all browsers to make them pick up the changed packages afterwards.

Comment: What @ByteCommander suggested may help you get it work in Firefox. Google Chrome, however, has Flash kind of built-in, and does not depend on any separate plugin, so the fact that it stopped working in Chrome sounds a bit odd.